# How to make notifications from one app to another app in django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am making one e-commerce website and i am just trying to make notifications from admin side to user side both are diffrent app in django...
My problems is how to make notifications in admin side (one app)when i click the button send the messages and display the notifications or message in userside(other app)

Comment: You can use [Django-signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) for sending notifications whenever some event occurs. For notifications I recommend use this [package](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to notify all the users ( for example for a new offer) when they login to their accounts.
For this matter, you must create a model for the notification (and if it's user-specified there is need for a foreign key to the user in the notification model or maybe you want to show the notification to all users by date this varies duo to your application) and in the profile view just make a query on notifications and show them to the user.

but if you want a chat room like notification (show notification to online users only) just use Django channels.